# AsyncCalls AsyncCallEx E2036 Variable required

Tags: delphi

Delphi 10.1 Berlin

I am unable to understood why I am getting error.

I get the error message when compile this (while TestRec is simple function - all is ok):

```
type
  TData = record
    Value: string;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    function TestRec(var Data: TData): Integer;
  end;

...

function TForm1.TestRec(var Data: TData): Integer;
begin
  Data.Value := 'TestOut';

  Result := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyData: TData;

  a: IAsyncCall;
begin
  MyData.Value := 'TestIn';

  a := AsyncCallEx(@TestRec, MyData); //[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(47): E2036 Variable required
end;
```

Error Shown:
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(47): E2036 Variable required

Comment: @TestRec isn't a variable, but MyData is. Which doesn't much make sense given the code you show and the error message. Are you quite sure you have transcribed things correctly. A simple MCVE in a console app would remove doubt.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, see my [link](https://github.com/ahausladen/AsyncCalls/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md) to the library documentation. In the example for the `AsyncCallEx`, a call to a normal function is done that way.

Comment: @LURD The asker has supplied the example code from that link and reports an error message that does not seem credible, no?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the the error message is because the asker changed the function parameter to a method (stated in the question as well). Passing a function parameter, the compiler accepts both `@TestRec` and `TestRec`.

Comment: It's an odd error message I think. Variable required? I don't see it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I don't tend to argue with the compiler, whether right or wrong, code must be changed to compile :-)

Comment: No, I was just trying to get my head round why the compiler had that to say

Comment: `@` operator usage is invalid here. Should be either `@TForm1.TestRec` or `class function TestRec; static`

Answer (score 4):

The signature for the overloaded `AsyncCallEx()` that accepts a method is:

```
function AsyncCallEx(Method: TAsyncCallArgRecordMethod; var Arg{: TRecordType}): IAsyncCall;
```

The correct way to reference the method in the call is:

```
a := AsyncCallEx(TestRec, MyData);
```

---

Since the method declaration of the method is:

```
TAsyncCallArgRecordMethod = function(var Arg{: TRecordType}): integer of object;
```

you will have to strip the data type from the method argument in `TestRec`.

```
function TestRec(var Data{: TData}): Integer;
```

---

The `AsyncCallEx` is from the library [AsyncCalls](https://github.com/ahausladen/AsyncCalls).

Answer (score 0):

Correct example code, thahk to @LU RD:

```
type
  TData = record
    Value: string;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    MyData: TData; //Global variable

    procedure {function} TestRec(var Data){: Integer}; //procedure or function
  end;

...

uses AsyncCalls;

...

procedure {function} TForm1.TestRec(var Data){: Integer}; //untyped parameters
begin
  TData(Data).Value := 'TestOut'; //cast to type

  //Result := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: IAsyncCall;
begin
  MyData.Value := 'TestIn';

  a := AsyncCallEx(TestRec, MyData); //without @ !!!
end;
```